# Error trying to create a browser with selenium in python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to use `selenium` in `python3` to force the execution of a `javascript` and get back / parse the rendered `html` with `BeautifulSoup` afterwards. Unfortunately I get stopped very quickly when trying to use `selenium`. I do :

```
>>> import platform
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Safari()
```

But then get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Safari()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/safari/webdriver.py", line 48, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 99, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Do you have any clue what I do wrong?

Comment: I found https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/, which, under the heading "Running the Example in Safari", explains how to get SafariDriver to work. That didn't work for me but it might work for you. please tell us what versions of Safari and selenium you have. The link I posted explains that there is a new SafariDriver which comes with Safari 10. For that reason, I'm skeptical that Andersson's answer is correct, because the first page he links to says that SafariDriver requires Safari 5.1+.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SafariDriver extension manually, see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver).

Basically, download the driver [from here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) with Safari, according to your Selenium version. And click install.

After that, your python code should work. (again, it depends on versions... not all Safari versions are supported, especially on Windows)